# Feynman-Kac for dividend stream

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, conditional-expectation

Suppose an asset value process $V_t$ that solves the PDE
$$dV_t=\mu V_tdt+\sigma V_tdW_t \text{ with }\mu\in\mathbb{R},\sigma>0, W \text{ Brownian Motion}.$$
I want to price a dividend stream $D_T=\int _0 ^Td(V_s)ds$ for a bounded function $d(v)$. Therefore I need to derive the conditional expectation:
$$E_{(t,V_t)}\left(\int_t ^T e^{-r(s-t)}d(V_s)ds\right)$$
for constant $r>0$.
I fail in deriving the necessary PDE to ensure that the value process is a (local) martingale. As a solution I have given the following:
Suppose that the bounded function $F:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the PDE
$$F_t+\mu vF_v+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2v^2F_{vv}+d(t,v)=rF(t,v)$$ with terminal condition $F(T,v)=0$. 
I try the following:
Let $Z(t,V)=\int_t ^T e^{-r(s-t)}d(V_s)ds=\int_t ^T Y_s ds.$ Following Itô it can be shown that $dY_s=e^{-r(s-t)}[(-rd+d_t+d_v\mu v+\frac{1}{2}d_{vv}\sigma^2v^2)dt+d_vv\sigma dW_t]$. However, how can I write $dZ=Z_tdt+Z_YdY+\frac{1}{2}Z_{YY}d{Y}$?

Comment: I think you can't write $dZ$ like that since it is not an integral with respect to the Wiener process but time. I would try to switch the time integral and expectation. But economically, shouldn't the asset value be equal to the dividend stream?

Comment: Okay, thank you! But isn't $Z$ also a variable of the itô process $Y$? Regarding your question, I think the asset value today should be equal to the discounted future payoffs, therefore the formula makes sense in my mind. Let me try to take into account your comment regarding switching the time integral and the expectation: Then I'd be interested in computing $\int_t ^T E_{(s,V_s)}[Y_s]ds=\int_t ^T e^{-r(s-t)}[d(s,V_s)]ds$ (Given I make use of $d$ satisfies the PDE. Isn't this exactly my starting point?